# Having issues with trying to make a view that uses 1 standard table and 1 Linking table

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, datagrip

So I have a DGV (DataGridView) that shows a list of **medication** that a **patient** was given to. Now I am trying to show the name of the **medication** rather than the ID in DGV.

[Picture of the DGV](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s6BpV.png)

I was hoping to do this with Table Views when I figured this issue but ran into another one for some reason I can't get it to write instances that only exist on the side of the linking table...
This and ER Model by VS
[Picture of the part of the ER](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jTRa6.png)

So the result of it all is that it will write instances that should not exist and that's a problem because I am filtering the medication by the ID of the patient examination called "ID nalaza"

[View data (there are 50+ instances in total)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eLooc.png)

while these 2 are the tables I am trying to connect
[Tables instances](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yilkb.png)

Any ideas on how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a DataGridView combo box to do it. You might have to adjust some of the advice below because you didn't post any code

Let's say we have Patients and Medicines and a Patient has. MedicineId for the medicine they take. In reality this would probably be a many:many relationship (many patients take same medicine, same patient takes many medicine) but DGV cannot display such, you have to repeat the rows for that, and that's a different technique - let's have a DGV that shows a patient and a medicine for now and you can expand it to show multiple rows for that patient later

So you've got your DGV showing your patient id, name, medicineid:

```
DGV.DataSource = context.Patients
  .Where(p => p.Name == "John")
  .Select(p => new PatientViewModel(p.Id, p.Name, p.MedicineId))
  .ToList()
```

Add another column to the DGV:

```
var dgvcbc = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
dgvcbc.HeaderText = "Medicine";
dgvcbc.DataMember = "MedicineId";  //the name of the column in the patients table
dgvcbc.ValueMember = "Val"; // the name of the property representing the medicine Id in the anonymous type below
dgvcbc.DisplayMember = "Disp"; // the name of the property in the AT below, representing the text to show in the combo 
dgvcbc.DataSource = context.Medicines
  .Select(m => new { Val = m.Id, Disp = m.Name } )
  .ToList();  //a query that generates a key value pair into an AT for use with Display/Value newbies above
```

The combo will read the medicine Id from the patient and lookup the text to show. If you change the combo (select  another item) the combo will push the new medicine Id into the patient list - this is a two way "binding"

Comment: Found another way by using .include("table_name") in my LINQ query, If the table is in the navigation properties of the table I am filtering then it will list a specific string that I defined in a partial class of the table I am trying to get the column from. 

it's not perfect but it will do the job, thanks anyways :D